# R Package Warning: multiple methods tables found for 'direction'

Tags: r, package, spatial, cran

I am maintaining an R package for spatial data. When I run checks on R-devel (Windows), I get: `"Warning: multiple methods tables found for 'direction'"`, which prohibits me from resubmitting my R package. I've checked and there is only one function `direction()` which is from the `raster` package - a package I don't explicitly import, but is suggested in `sf` which I do. Any ideas of what this could be/a workaround?

Comment: I had the same error today and just got an e-mail from Uwe Ligges saying that it was an error on their end.  Hopefully it will be the same for you.

Comment: Thank you! @DaveArmstrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> library(sp)
> library(raster)
Warning messages:
1: multiple methods tables found for 'direction' 
2: multiple methods tables found for 'gridDistance'
```

New session:

```
> raster::direction
standardGeneric for "direction" defined from package "raster"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("direction")
<bytecode: 0x8163a60>
<environment: 0x81349e0>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods(direction)  for currently available ones.
Warning messages:
1: multiple methods tables found for 'direction' 
2: multiple methods tables found for 'gridDistance' 
> terra::direction
standardGeneric for "direction" defined from package "terra"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("direction")
<bytecode: 0x312a030>
<environment: 0x30e2640>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods(direction)  for currently available ones.
```

It looks as though both **raster** and **terra** define these generics, **terra** 1.5-12 was just published. Resolution:
https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/485#issuecomment-1012466626, re-install **raster** after **terra**.